# JAXB instance nullability/validity with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

With JAX-RS, do I have to check the JAXB element?

Can(Should) the container to check the content validity?

Can(Should) the container automatically responses BAD_REQUEST while unmarshalling `Item` before invoking REST method?

Can(May) the container responses INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR when client sent unmarshallable(or empty) content?

```java
@XmlRootElement
class Item {
}

@PUT
@Path("/items/{item_id: \\d+}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response updateItem(@PathParam("item_id") final Long itemId,
                       final Item item) {

    assert itemId != null; // '\\d+'


    assert item != null; // is this make any sense?

    // is it ok to assert item is never null?
}
```

One more question, what about `byte[]`?

```java
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
@PUT
@Path("/players/{player_id: \\d+}/picture");
public Response updatePicture(..., final byte[] bytes) {

    assert bytes != null;

   // is it ok to assert bytes won't be null even for an empty request body?

}
```

Oops, I think I found the answer.

http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-460004.2.4

> When reading zero-length request entities, all implementation-supplied
>   MessageBodyReader implementations **except the JAXB-related** one MUST
>   create a corresponding Java object that represents **zero-length data**;
>   they **MUST NOT return null**. The implementation-supplied **JAXB**
>   MessageBodyReader implementation **MUST throw a WebApplicationException**
>   with a client error response (**HTTP 400**) for zero-length request
>   entities.